# Non iterable data from API in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, django-rest-framework

I am working on a restaurant review app using DjangoRest and Vue.js. I have made a component to display each review pictures.

I fetch the data using this api.service.js (*I am using it to fetch the data through all my app and it's working just fine*):

```
import { CSRF_TOKEN } from "./csrf_token.js"
function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.status === 204) {
    return '';
  } else if (response.status === 404) {
    return null;
  } else {
    return response.json();
  }  
}
function apiService(endpoint, method, data) {
  const config = {
    method: method || "GET",
    body: data !== undefined ? JSON.stringify(data) : null,
    headers: {
      'content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFTOKEN': CSRF_TOKEN
    }
  };
  return fetch(endpoint, config)
          .then(handleResponse)
          .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
export { apiService };
```

But I can't make this component to work:

```
 <template>
  <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
 </template>

<script>
import { apiService } from "@/common/api.service.js";
export default {
  name: "ReviewDetail",
  data () {
    return {      
      pictures: [],           
    }
  },
  props: {
    id: {
      type: Number,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getPictures() {
      let endpoint = `every_review_pics/${this.id}/`;           
      apiService(endpoint)        
        .then(data => {          
          this.pictures.push(...data)                       
      })
      console.log(data)
    },    
  },
  created() {      
    this.getPictures()    
  } 
};
```

I have 'console logged' my endpoint to check with my props where correctly passed and everything work fine.
Here is the data I want to retrieve:

[image]

I `console.log(data)` just after the `apiService` is called and i get this error:
[image]

Comment: `console.log(data)` and see what it actually is.

Comment: i think you forgot to specify your problem

Comment: Yes it is. Does it change anything?

Answer (score 0):

Shame on me. I forgot to add `/api/` at the beginning of my endpoint. Sorry Leo Lee for your time :(